# Как добавить в код программно класс active?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Справочник Android</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AndroidHelp.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left">
        <ul>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\2.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\3.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\4.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\5.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\6.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\7.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\8.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\9.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\10.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\11.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\12.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\13.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\14.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\15.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\16.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\17.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\18.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\19.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\20.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\21.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\22.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\23.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\24.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\25.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\26.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\27.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <iframe name="question" id="iframe"></iframe>


</body>
</html>
```

Я хочу изменить цвет кнопки. чтобы изменить надо прописать class="active"

но как сделать это программно? так как у меня сайт работает без обновления всей страницы.

Исплользуя iFrame....
Есть ли способ?

Comment: Да, способ есть - JavaScript

Comment: Можно и с помощью CSS добавить соответствующее оформление. Это альтернатива варианту с JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слегка упрощенный вариант без циклов

```
$('#left a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Убрать, чтобы ссылка работала

  $('#left a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно добавить с помощью js. Только последнюю строчку где комментарий написан уберите потом.

```js
var questionLinks = $('a');

$('a').click(function(e) {
  $.each(questionLinks, function(index, link) {
    $(link).removeClass('active');
  })
  $(this).addClass('active');

  e.preventDefault(); // Убрать, чтобы ссылка работала
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left">
  <ul>
    <li><a target="question" href="HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a>
    </li>
    <li><a target="question" href="HTML\2.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a>
    </li>
    <li><a target="question" href="HTML\3.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a>
    </li>
    <li><a target="question" href="HTML\4.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a>
    </li>
    <li><a target="question" href="HTML\5.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<iframe name="question" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

Если класс active необязателен, то лучше стили написать:

```css
a:focus {
  color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <ul>
    <li><a target="question" href="#">Прослушка Радиостанции</a>
    </li>
    <li><a target="question" href="#">Прослушка Радиостанции</a>
    </li>
    <li><a target="question" href="#">Прослушка Радиостанции</a>
    </li>
    <li><a target="question" href="#">Прослушка Радиостанции</a>
    </li>
    <li><a target="question" href="#">Прослушка Радиостанции</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<iframe name="question" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var removeClass = function (){
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i< links.length; i++){
  links[i].classList.remove('active');
}
}
```

```css
.active {
    text-align: center;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Справочник Android</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AndroidHelp.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left">
        <ul>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\1.html" onclick="removeClass(); this.classList.add('active')">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\2.html" onclick="removeClass(); this.classList.add('active')">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\3.html" onclick="removeClass(); this.classList.add('active')">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\4.html" onclick="removeClass(); this.classList.add('active')">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\5.html" onclick="removeClass(); this.classList.add('active')">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\6.html" onclick="removeClass(); this.classList.add('active')">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\7.html" onclick="removeClass(); this.classList.add('active')">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\8.html" onclick="removeClass(); this.classList.add('active')">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a target="question" href="HTML\9.html" onclick="removeClass(); this.classList.add('active')">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>          
        </ul>
    </div>
    <iframe name="question" id="iframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Надеюсь такой код сойдет

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без JQuery:

```js
//декларируем коллекцию элементов
var my_elems = document.getElementsByClassName("radio-station");
// обработчик клика для элементов из коллекции
function add_class_active (event) {
  for(var i=0; i < my_elems.length; i++)
    {
        my_elems[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  event.target.className += " active";
  }
// привязка событий к элементам колекции
function init() {
  for(var i=0; i < my_elems.length; i++)
    {
        my_elems[i].onclick = add_class_active;
    }

  }
// запуск
init();
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: green;
  }
.radio-station {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Справочник Android</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AndroidHelp.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left">
        <ul id = "stations">
           <li><a class="radio-station active" target="question" href="HTML\1.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\2.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\3.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\4.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\5.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\6.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\7.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\8.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\9.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\10.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\11.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\12.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\13.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\14.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class = "radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\15.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\16.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\17.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\18.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\19.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\20.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\21.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\22.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\23.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\24.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\25.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\26.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
           <li><a class="radio-station" target="question" href="HTML\27.html">Прослушка Радиостанции</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```